# Change a column containing list of dict to columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following DataFrame which contains a column that is a list of dict items:

```
    d = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Green', [{'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO'}, {'Sec:': '01'}, {'Lot:': 'L0038'}, {'Block:': 'B0008'}]],
        ['Apply', [{'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO'}, {'Sec:': '01'}, {'Lot:': 'L0038'}, {'Block:': 'B0008'}]],
        ['Range', [{'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO'}, {'Sec:': '01'}, {'Lot:': 'L0038'}, {'Block:': 'B0008'}]],
        ['Peop',  [{'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO'}, {'Sec:': '01'}, {'Lot:': 'L0038'}, {'Block:': 'B0008'}]]
        ], columns=['Name', 'Legal Description'])
```

and I want to transform it to a simple DataFrame like so:

```
    d = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Green', 'STERLING GREEN SO', '01', 'L0038', 'B0008'],
        ['Apply', 'STERLING GREEN SO', '01', 'L0038', 'B0008'],
        ['Range', 'STERLING GREEN SO', '01', 'L0038', 'B0008'],
        ['Peop',  'STERLING GREEN SO', '01', 'L0038', 'B0008']
        ], columns=['Name', 'Legal Description', 'Desc', 'Sec', 'Lot', 'Block'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, the ideal solution would be to act upstream and get a properly formatted dictionary or dataframe.

The issue with your list of single-keyed dictionaries is that you have to merge them. You can use a dictionary comprehension for that and convert to Series:

```
d2 = d['Legal Description'].apply(lambda c:
                                  pd.Series({next(iter(x.keys())).strip(':'):
                                             next(iter(x.values())) for x in c})
                                  )
```

Then join to the original dataframe:

```
d.drop(columns='Legal Description').join(d2)
```

output:

```
    Name               Desc Sec    Lot  Block
0  Green  STERLING GREEN SO  01  L0038  B0008
1  Apply  STERLING GREEN SO  01  L0038  B0008
2  Range  STERLING GREEN SO  01  L0038  B0008
3   Peop  STERLING GREEN SO  01  L0038  B0008
```

Comment: That was awesomely quick and elegant! 2 questions, I have a little control over the source, what would a properly formatted dictionary look like for this example?  And more important, where can I learn what you did!

Comment: 1- run `d.drop(columns='Legal Description').join(d2).to_dict('list')` and this will give you a nice format to feed to `pd.DataFrame`. 2- hard to tell you, it's not much *where*, most important in my opinion is to code, try to solve problems and to improve what you did. Read a lot selected forums/books/good answers on this site and keep a critical mind ;)

Answer (score 2):

If possible, you should wrangle your data before creating the DataFrame. It's faster than reshaping the DataFrame after being created. For instance, something like

```
data = [
    ['Green', [{'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO'}, {'Sec:': '01'}, {'Lot:': 'L0038'}, {'Block:': 'B0008'}]],
    ['Apply', [{'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO'}, {'Sec:': '01'}, {'Lot:': 'L0038'}, {'Block:': 'B0008'}]],
    ['Range', [{'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO'}, {'Sec:': '01'}, {'Lot:': 'L0038'}, {'Block:': 'B0008'}]],
    ['Peop',  [{'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO'}, {'Sec:': '01'}, {'Lot:': 'L0038'}, {'Block:': 'B0008'}]]
]

records = []

for name, legal_desc in data:
    rec = {'Name': name}
    rec.update(x for d in legal_desc for x in d.items())
    records.append(rec)
    
d = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Output:

```
>>> d

    Name              Desc: Sec:   Lot: Block:
0  Green  STERLING GREEN SO   01  L0038  B0008
1  Apply  STERLING GREEN SO   01  L0038  B0008
2  Range  STERLING GREEN SO   01  L0038  B0008
3   Peop  STERLING GREEN SO   01  L0038  B0008

>>> records 

[{'Name': 'Green', 'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO', 'Sec:': '01', 'Lot:': 'L0038', 'Block:': 'B0008'}, {'Name': 'Apply', 'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO', 'Sec:': '01', 'Lot:': 'L0038', 'Block:': 'B0008'}, {'Name': 'Range', 'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO', 'Sec:': '01', 'Lot:': 'L0038', 'Block:': 'B0008'}, {'Name': 'Peop', 'Desc:': 'STERLING GREEN SO', 'Sec:': '01', 'Lot:': 'L0038', 'Block:': 'B0008'}]
```

Comment: I have never seen the syntax "name, legal_desc = row" before, what is it doing, where can I use it?  Also how does this compare to "for name, legal_desc in data" ?

Comment: @QuentinJS If you understand what `for name, legal_desc in data` does, then you understand the syntax `name, legal_desc = row`. It's the same principle, it's called iterable unpacking. Each `row` is a list with two elements, and the assignment is just unpacking the elements and assigning them to different variables,  But actually, your suggestion is better, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
df =  df['Legal Description'].explode().apply(pd.Series).groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()
```

`OUTPUT`

```
    Name              Desc: Sec:   Lot: Block:
0  Apply  STERLING GREEN SO   01  L0038  B0008
1  Green  STERLING GREEN SO   01  L0038  B0008
2   Peop  STERLING GREEN SO   01  L0038  B0008
3  Range  STERLING GREEN SO   01  L0038  B0008
```