# convert column of lists of dictionaries to separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have:

```
grp = ["A","B","C","A","C","C","B"]
dictl = ["[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:30.957'}]",
"[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:30.957'}]",
"[]","[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504'}]",
"[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504'}]",
"[]","[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504'}]"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'grp':grp,'dictl':dictl})
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
pd.DataFrame({'grp':["A","B","C","A","C","C","B"],
              'TypeID':["0","0","","0","0","","0"],
              'Description':["blah","blah","","blah","blah","","blah"],
              'DateCreated':["2018-08-09T14:00:30.957","2018-08-09T14:00:30.957","","2018-08-09T14:00:31.504","2018-08-09T14:00:31.504","","2018-08-09T14:00:31.504"]})
```

I tried suggestions from [Change a column containing list of dict to columns in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488100/change-a-column-containing-list-of-dict-to-columns-in-a-dataframe), and had the following issues:

```
for grp, dictl in df:
    rec = {'Name': grp}
    rec.update(x for d in dictl for x in d.items())
    records.append(rec)
```

error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

and

```
df['dictl'].apply(lambda c:
                                  pd.Series({next(iter(x.keys())).strip(':'):
                                             next(iter(x.values())) for x in c})
                                  )
```

gave error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`

I have > 2m rows, so would like this method to be quick if possible

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to convert `TypeID`, which seems to be an integer 0, into a string "0"?

Comment: Same question about the timestamps: these are all strings, and in particular the default value is an empty string. Of course, conversion can always be done after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your stringified input, you can do this:

```
groups = ["A","B","C","A","C","C","B"]
strings = ["[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:30.957'}]",
"[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:30.957'}]",
"[]","[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504'}]",
"[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504'}]",
"[]","[{'TypeID': 0, 'Description': 'blah', 'DateCreated': '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504'}]"]

import ast

dictl = [ast.literal_eval(string) for string in strings]

# In case of missing data
defaults = {'TypeID': 0, 'Description': '', 'DateCreated': ''}

# Some fancy list comprehension-ternary if-dict creation, because why not?
dictl_grp = [{**item[0], 'grp': group} if len(item)
             else {'grp': group, **defaults} 
             for group, item in zip(groups, dictl)]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dictl_grp)
print(df)
```

which yields

```
   TypeID Description              DateCreated grp
0       0        blah  2018-08-09T14:00:30.957   A
1       0        blah  2018-08-09T14:00:30.957   B
2       0                                        C
3       0        blah  2018-08-09T14:00:31.504   A
4       0        blah  2018-08-09T14:00:31.504   C
5       0                                        C
6       0        blah  2018-08-09T14:00:31.504   B
```

(I renamed a few variables for clarity.)

Comment: the empty records match to a specific group from the `grp` column, so they are needed. I tried `[ast.literal_eval(string)[0] if string is not '[]' else '' for string in df.dictl ]`, but that is not working --> `syntax warning`

Comment: great, can you explain the fancy list comprehension-ternary thing for me

Comment: @frank A full explanation might be tricky, because I don't know what you already understand (for example, do you know about `zip()`?). I'll point you to two relevant questions: [if-else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) and [How can I merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python/26853961#26853961). Hopefully that gives you some insight.

Comment: this is what I am more confused about:  `{**item[0], 'grp': group} if len(item)  else {'grp': group, **defaults} `. , the `**item[0]` and `**defaults` bit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the data, before loading it into a dataframe, one approach is to first extract the keys from the first, non-empty item

```
>>> keys = [k for k in eval(next(i for i in dictl if i != "[]"))[0]]
>>> keys
['TypeID', 'Description', 'DateCreated']
```

and then create your new dict by reading them from the records:

```
>>> newdict = {key: [eval(it)[0].get(key) if it != "[]" else "" for it in dictl] for key in keys}
>>> newdict
{'TypeID': [0, 0, '', 0, 0, '', 0], 'Description': ['blah', 'blah', '', 'blah', 'blah', '', 'blah'], 'DateCreated': ['2018-08-09T14:00:30.957', '2018-08-09T14:00:30.957', '', '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504', '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504', '', '2018-08-09T14:00:31.504']}
```

Note that I am using `eval` here for simplicity, `ast.literal_eval` is usually the safer choice.